# Find the recursive formula for $a_{n}={b^n}$ for $n>2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms

How can I solve it,
and can anybody help me to find recursive formula for $a_{n}=3n^3$ for $n\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you mean you are looking for a formula of the form $a_{n+1}=f\big( a_n\big)$, for some function $f$?

Comment: Looking at your formula (for the first problem), if I say that $a_{100}=x$, can you say what $a_{101}$ equals?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, what happened when you wrote down the formula for $a_{n+1}$? Take a look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for hints on how to improve your question, and in particular look [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) for how to avoid "I have no clue" questions.

Comment: Hint: Consider $n=(a_n/3)^{1/3}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $b_n=a_{n+1}-a_n=3(n+1)^3-3n^3=9n^2+9n+3$

Set $c_n=b_{n+1}-b_n=9(n+1)^2+9(n+1)+3-(9n^2+9n+3)=18n+18$

So $c_{n+1}=c_n+18$ and $c_0=18$

Then $b_{n+2}-b_{n+1}=b_{n+1}-b_n+18$

then $a_{n+3}-a_{n+2}-(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-(a_{n+1}-a_n)+18$

So $a_{n+3}=3a_{n+2}-3a_{n+1}+a_n+18$, with $a_0=0, a_1=3, a_2=24$

Answer (score 3):

We have $a_{n+1}=3(n+1)^3=3(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)=a_n+9n^2+9n+3$. And $a_0=0$.

Comment: can yo solve for an=b^n for n>2

Comment: If $a_n=b^n$, then $a_n=ba_{n-1}\,,n\ge1$, with $a_0=1$.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to try to consider $a_n=3((n-1)+1)^3$ and see what you can get out of it.